# Attributeerror module pyglet.media has no Attribute 'Player' cx_Freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze, attributeerror, pyglet

```
import pyglet
import time
import random

# Program for setup audio 
while True:
    x = random.randint(600,3600)
    player = pyglet.media.Player()
    sound = pyglet.media.load('file2.mp3')
    player.queue(sound) 

    # keep playing for as long as the app is running (or you tell it to stop):
    player.eos_action = pyglet.media.SourceGroup.loop

    player.play()
    time.sleep(x)
    input("Press Enter")
```

And use this code for setup.py

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import pyglet
import time
import random
import sys

base=None

if sys.platform=='win32':
    base="WIN32GUI"

includes = ['pyglet']
includes = ['time']
includes = ['random']
includes = ['sys']

setup(
    name = "Alarm",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Alarm",
    executables = [Executable("Alarm.py")]
)
```

When it has finished I a have folder build, it's ok. But when I click on .exe file in the build folder,
I have this error:

> Attributeerror module pyglet.media has no Attribute 'Player' cx_Freeze

Help please. What should I do?